# Meteor not detecting package

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, telescope

Following [this tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/02/build-your-own-product-hunt-with-telescope-and-meteor/), I created a simple `package.js` referring to a css file `qocustom.css` kept in the same directory `qopackage`

So inside the `qopackage` folder is the `package.js` and the `qocustom.css` files.

I have tried:

1. moving this folder to `/root/.meteor/packages/` (quest is the project name)
2. moving this folder to `/root/quest/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/packages/` (quest is the project name)

And with both attempts,

Trying:

`sudo meteor add qopackage`

Returns:

```
=> Errors while parsing arguments:

While adding package qopackage:
error: no such package
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

**---- EDIT ----**

Here's the content of the two files:

Package.js:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: 'QuestOrganizer custom package',
  version: '1.0.0',
  name: 'qo-custom'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {  
  api.addFiles('qocustom.css', 'client');
});
```

qocustom.css:

```
hero .copy {
    top: 3%
}
.btn {
    border radius:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages need to go into `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/packages/packagename`. So in your case, try moving these files into `/root/quest/packages/qopackage`. Afterwards you should be able to add them to your project.

As an aside, and you probably know that: running your project as root/sudo is probably not a good idea in terms of security.

**UPDATE:**

It's easier though to ask meteor to setup the package structure for you:

```
meteor create --package qopackage
```

Comment: But there is no folder named `packages` directly under quest though. I have to go `/local/build/programs/web.browser/` to find the packages folder and there's also another pacakges folder in the server directory too.

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist yet then you'll need to create it. You shouldn't do anything in .meteor/local. That get's overwritten all the time.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try creating a new directory in the project directory then.

Comment: Ok I added a folder named `packages` inside of the `quest` folder and I still can't run `meteor add qopackage` unfortunately.

Comment: The structure now is: `/quest/packages/qopackage`

Comment: The same one Christian:

`=> Errors while parsing arguments:

While adding package qopackage:
error: no such package`

Comment: ok, well, then just forget about creating the package manually, and ask meteor to do it for you (see my edit to the answer). You can then edit the package.js file meteor creates and it will surely work.

Comment: Ok now this weird. Running the above gave me this: `qopackage: Already exists in your app`

Comment: yes, because you already have that folder, per my instructions above. Just move it away and try the command again.